# Using View in MXML

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

When using this following code..

```
           <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
```

It shows the error

Could not resolve s:View>  to a component implementation

Can anyone tell why it is happening?

Comment: what SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make sure that your SDK is available, So check the path. Just right click on your project>goto properties>Flex Compiler> Check whats selected.

There is no harm in trying to download SDK again and overwrite your existing SDK with the downloadeded one. Make sure you download the same version though. This way you can be sure that there is nothing wrong with the SDK.